# Как отловить событие другого скрипта?

Tags: javascript

Есть фотогалерея на JS. Которая показывает обычным пользователям фоточки в модальном окне. Надо сделать, чтобы у админа в этом же окне добавлялись некоторые кнопочки (например "отметить человека").

Думал при загрузке страницы проверять права юзеров, и, если зашел админ, подключать еще один JS-файл, который добавляет функционал. Т.е. при нажатии на миниатюру фотки, должна вызываться дополнительная функция из другого файла, которая добавит необходимые элементы.

Терзают смутные сомненья. Точно ли это сработает, да и вообще - хорошая это мысль, или есть более адекватные варианты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сработать вроде должно, если не накосячить :)

Вообще идея не часто встречаемая. Думаю по таким критериям можно определиться:

1. дополнительного функционала для админа много? Ради одной кнопочки огород не стоит городить.
2. Если есть разные права - т.е. админ, модер и т.д., то удобно будет подключать - одному одну библиотечку, другому - другую.

Вообще помните: лишние подключение к серверу - лишняя нагрузка. В основном на сервер и чу-чуть на пользователя. С другой стороны ваш вариант удобнее. **Так что выбирайте что вам важнее:**

1. если *оптимизация*, то *альтернативы*
2. если *удобство в коде, как для программиста,* то *ваше решение*

Answer (score 1):

Слегка не понял, в чём именно. Если проблема в реализации, то есть как сделать так, чтобы какой-то код выполнялся при каком-то событии модуля, то решение довольно простое. В самом модуле должна быть какая-то пустая функция, которую можно будет подменить.

```
//конфигурация модуля
onSomeMethod=function(){};
//код модуля
function someEvent(){
    onSomeMethod();
    //код события
}
```

А в другом скрипте, который грузится после загрузки первого, подмените нужную функцию:

```
onSomeMethod=function(){
    //нужный вам код
}
```

Разумеется, функции и переменные не отдельные, а как свойства/методы нужного обьекта.

Если проблема более абстрактна, [`danpetruk`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/233998/) всё описал выше.